# Control no longer transparent after refresh

Tags: c#

I have created myself a transparent Panel.

```
 public TransPanel()
{
}

protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {

        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;

        cp.ExStyle |= 0x00000020;

        return cp;

    }

}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (ImageForBackGround != null)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(ImageForBackGround, new Point(0, 0));
    }
}
```

It works fine, but i have the problem, that the control is no longer transparent if I do a .Refresh(); or a .Invalidate();. Then the Control just have the same color then his parent.
I already tried to override the BackgroundOnPaint-Event, but it doesnt work.

```
 protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
{

  Application.DoEvents();

}
```

Can somebody help me ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Forget to say: Im using Windows Forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found a solution now. Just set Opaque to true.

```
 protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ImageForBackGround != null)
        {
           e.Graphics.DrawImage(ImageForBackGround, new Point(0, 0));
           this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);

        }
    }
```